# Typed name of a program when in the parent directory. Did I open a can of worms?

Tags: 18.04

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

When I was in the parent directory in terminal, I typed the name of a program, Brave (it's a web browser).

The terminal "responded" with a lot of output, and I am unsure of what to make of it all.
I was really just goofing around and didn't think it would do anything. But, it did respond with a bunch of output and then open a browser window.  Is there anything in that output that I should do something about?
I pasted below what it said.

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Crash reporting enabled
[1671:1671:0518/233217.183485:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. %d listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.", source: chrome://brave/snap/brave/23/usr/lib/brave/resources/app.asar/app/extensions/brave/gen/app.entry.js (1)
[1671:1671:0518/233217.189543:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. %d listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.", source: chrome://brave/snap/brave/23/usr/lib/brave/resources/app.asar/app/extensions/brave/gen/app.entry.js (1)
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.69" (uid=1000 pid=1671 comm="/snap/brave/23/usr/bin/brave --no-sandbox " label="snap.brave.brave (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service" member="SearchItems" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.secrets" (uid=1000 pid=922 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login " label="unconfined")
{ version: '0.22.714',
  name: 'Brave 0.22.714',
  pub_date: '2018-05-15T21:26:07.627Z',
  notes: 'Improved browser performance (especially with a high number of tabs open), several improvements for Brave Payments. More details: https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/releases/tag/v0.22.714dev',
  preview: false,
  url: 'https://brave-download.global.ssl.fastly.net/multi-channel/releases/dev/0.22.714/linux64/Brave.tar.bz2' }
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.69" (uid=1000 pid=1671 comm="/snap/brave/23/usr/bin/brave --no-sandbox " label="snap.brave.brave (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.secrets" (uid=1000 pid=922 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login " label="unconfined")
```

Comment: Well done for trying new things.  No you didn't break anything, if you started `brave` from a menu you wouldn't see any of this as Mark Smith said in his answer. Most of these messages are just debug warnings useful to coders, or trouble-shooters in helping to see what is wrong & fix issues.  We ignore them when programs are working correctly, but they they're useful when we have problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common for programs to print stuff to the console like this. If there's a problem with the program you might find a clue here. If you launch the program from the launcher (click on it) you just don't see the output so you're blissfully unaware of it.

If the program is working properly and you're not trying to debug it, just ignore it. You haven't done any harm.